# SSIS Execution Cause Growing TempDB

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, ssis

I have Package Which Contains a Foreach Loop and inside It I have Task runner execution which executes a query without Order by or indexes
the code i exeduted inside is:

```
  declare @Sdate int 
set @Sdate=?
declare @Edate int 
set @Edate=?

---------------ActiveShowingType-------
update att.FactWorkPeriod
set ActiveShowingType=0 
update w 
set w.ActiveShowingType=case when w.ShowingTypeId=c.ShowingTypeID then 1
else 0 end
from att.FactWorkPeriod w 
inner join att.DimCode c on w.CodeId=c.[CodeId]
where w.DateSK between @Sdate and @Edate
 ----------------------  HasContract-------------------
  declare @YearStart char(4)=(select min (YearIR) from att.FactWorkPeriod w 
 inner join gnr.DimDate d on w.DateSK=d.DateSK)
 update w1 
set w1.HasContract =case when t.PersonSK is not null then 1 else 0 end 
from att.FactWorkPeriod w1
inner join (
select distinct
(select max(datesk) from gnr.dimdate dd where dd.yearmonthIR=d.YearMonthIR)as dateSK,
p.PersonSK
from gnr.DimDate d 
left join  att.DimPerson p on d.FullDateIR between p.EmployDate and p.ExitDate
 where  YearIR between @YearStart and (select YearIR from gnr.DimDate where IsToday=1)  and d.LastDayOfMonth=1
 )t on t.dateSK=w1.DateSK and t.PersonSK=w1.PersonSK
 where w1.DateSK between @Sdate and @Edate
 --------------------ContractTypeId------------------
 if (case when (select Count(isnull(GroupId ,0)) from kasrawarehouse.att.DimGroup)<1 then 0 else 1 end= 1 )
 begin 
 update w2
 set w2.ContractTypeId=t.ContractTypeId
  from att.FactWorkPeriod w2
 inner join ( select w3.DateSK , w3.PersonSK , case when gp.groupid is not null then 0
else 1 end as ContractTypeId from att.FactWorkPeriod w3
 inner join att.DimPerson p on w3.PersonSK=p.PersonSK
inner join gnr.DimDate d on d.DateSK=w3.DateSK
left join KasraForWarehouseConvert.gnr.GroupPerson gp 
 ON d.FullDateIR BETWEEN gp.SDate COLLATE Arabic_CI_AS AND gp.EDate COLLATE Arabic_CI_AS
 and gp.PersonelID=p.PersonBK
 and gp.GroupID in (select distinct GroupId from [Att].[DimGroup])--='15027' 
where d.LastDayOfMonth=1  )t on t.DateSK=w2.DateSK and t.PersonSK=w2.PersonSK
 where w2.DateSK between @Sdate and @Edate
 end 
  ---------------  به روز رسانی واحد سازمانی که از بین رفته ------
 update w4
set w4.OrgSK='999999999'
 from att.FactWorkPeriod w4
inner join (select distinct OrgSK from att.FactWorkPeriod w5
where w5.OrgSK not in (select distinct OrgIdPreffix from att.DimOrg)) t on t.OrgSK=w4.OrgSK
 where w4.DateSK between @Sdate and @Edate
 -------- پاک کردن افرادی که پاک شده اند -------
delete  from att.FactWorkPeriod 
where PersonSK not in (select distinct PersonSK from att.DimPerson)
and DateSK between @Sdate and @Edate
```

[image: SSIS Pic]

and During the execution tempDb Grows fast and stops when drive is full. how can i execute it without store it on tempDb and only insert and update Datas?
PS- i Run the code inside Sql Server And it works Without Problem.

Comment: How small if your storage device for it to be filled, or how much data are you trying to handle in one transaction? You can't stop SQL Server using `tempdb`, if it feels it needs to use it, for creating things like work tables, it will use it.

Answer (score 0):

TempDB is an optimized storage place that the SQL Engine may choose to use to process a query / operation depending on what it needs to do. When this occurs, it's use is necessary and the growth of the file(s) for TempDB are normal. You can read more about what specifically is stored in TempDB and how it's used by the SQL Engine in the Microsoft Docs [TempDB Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/tempdb-database?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15).

The storage consumed by the file(s) behind your TempDB may persist after the objects in TempDB no longer exist (because the SQL Engine doesn't natively release the consumed space back to the disk) but will be re-used by future operations (essentially the same bytes will be overwritten on disk) that use TempDB.

So you shouldn't be concerned so much about the growth you're seeing as it is both necessary and re-used in future operations (your TempDB won't exponentially grow when the same workload is being applied).

The only way you could limit it's use is to pre-grow the file(s) of your TsmpDB to the size you want to cap it at, and reduce the allocated free space on disk where those files live so there is nothing left to grow to. But this would be a very bad practice to do, and likely result in many performance problems for your queries and processes.